# Trouble writing a structure to a file in Linux, giving Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

I have a method here that is taking inputs from the user and storing them to a file in Linux. I am currently getting a segmentation fault somewhere after getting the index input and while I think its from the fwrite method, I'm not sure. I thought that there might be a null character at the end of the structure but making the size of fwrite "sizeof(sr)+1" still gives a segmentation fault so I think that rules that out.

```
void
put(int32_t fd)
{
    sr s;

    printf("Enter the student name: "); 
    char name [30];
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);
    name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0';
    strcpy(s.name, name);

    // WRITE THE CODE to read the name from stdin
    // store it in s.name
    // use fgets()
    // fgets doesnt remove newline. replace '\n' with '\0' in s.name. strlen() will be useful
    

    printf("Enter the student id: ");
    char sidC[15];
    fgets(sidC, 15, stdin);
    int32_t sid = atoi(sidC);
    s.sid = sid;
    //
    // WRITE THE CODE to read student id from stdin
    // store it in s.sid
    

    printf("Enter the record index: ");
    char indexC[5];
    //under here
    fgets(indexC, 5, stdin);
    int32_t index = atoi(indexC);
    s.index = index;
    //
    // WRITE THE CODE to read record index from stdin
    // store it in s.index


    // WRITE THE CODE to seek to the appropriate offset in fd (lseek(), sizeof() will be useful)
    lseek(fd, sizeof(sr)*(index-1), SEEK_SET);

    // WRITE THE CODE to write record s to fd
    fwrite((char*)&s, sizeof(sr), 1, fd);
    
}
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `struct sr`.

Comment: `fwrite` works with a `FILE*`, not a file descriptor. You need to use `write`.

Comment: If your compiler does not warn you about that type mismatch in your parameters, you should clearly increase warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 0):

Without the definition of `struct sr` it's going to be difficult to say, but I bet that you have:

```
typedef struct sr {
  char *name;
  ...
} sr;
```

Which means that when you do `strcpy(s.name, ...);` you are writing into unallocated memory.